# Запрос GET в Postman срабатывает через раз, когда переменным в Environment присваиваются Динамические переменные

Tags: javascript, api, тестирование, postman

Тестирую API **[https://petstore.swagger.io](https://petstore.swagger.io/)**

У меня два метода:
POST создает Юзера. Вот этот https://petstore.swagger.io/#/user/createUser

**В body запроса:**

```
{
    "id": {{$randomInt}},
    "username": "{{usr}}",
    "firstName": "{{$randomFirstName}}",
    "lastName": "{{$randomLastName}}",
    "email": "{{$randomEmail}}",
    "password": "{{pwd}}",
    "phone": "{{$randomPhoneNumber}}",
    "userStatus": 0
}
```

**В pre-request Script:**

```
var randName = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 7);
var randPass = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 6);

pm.environment.set("usr", randName, String);
pm.environment.set("pwd", randPass, String);
```

**Этот запрос отрабатывает нормально.**

А вот **GET запрос**, который вытаскивает только что созданного с помощью POST юзера, срабатывает через раз (именно через раз).

Речь о вот этом запросе: https://petstore.swagger.io/#/user/loginUser

**Endpoint запроса выглядит вот так:
{{base_url}}/user/{{usr}}**

```
{{base_url}} = https://petstore.swagger.io/v2
{{usr}} - берется из environment
```

Ничего не понимаю, иногда он падает с 404:

```
{
    "code": 1,
    "type": "error",
    "message": "User not found"
}
```

Но при повторном запуске все отрабатывает нормально и он возвращает созданного юзера.

Но если в В pre-request Script POST запроса захардкодить данные в usr, а не брать переменные окружения и динамические переменные faker, то GET запрос начинает работать нормально.

Comment: "если в В pre-request Script POST запроса захардкодить данные в usr, а не брать переменные окружения и динамические переменные faker" --- значит вывод какой? Проблема не в постмане.

Comment: Вы случаем не на Астре Линукс?))

Comment: Нет, на винде 10. Если честно вообще не пойму в чем проблема и то, что работает через раз - еще страннее. Я попробовал выводить в консоль содержимое переменной окружения в пре-реквест скрипте, он выводит, оно там есть. Но во время запроса такое ощущение, что это значение слетает периодически и ноги у ошибки отсюда и растут.

Comment: Может ли быть так, что после добавления новой записи необходимо какое-то время? Попробуйте выполнять запросы с интервалом, либо попробуйте своё API вместо публичного (благо для этого можно [сгенерировать клиента](https://editor.swagger.io) автоматически).